# Frameset not working

Tags: css, html, iframe, frameset

I'm doing a frameset with two pages, the first page is 'index.php', which would be the page with the main content of my site. 
The second page is the 'mp3.html', which is an mp3 player that should be aligned to the footer.

I did get the frameset but only a white screen appears. 
What could be my problem?

HTML frameset page (intro.php) => http://pastebin.com/enJeVXSG

```
<body>
    <frameset rows="*,30" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>index.php" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" />
        <frame src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>mp3.html" name="bottomFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="bottomFrame" />
    </frameset>
</body>
```

mp3.html => http://pastebin.com/0ShSj3RA

```
<div class="player">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ... /></object>
</div>
```

I'm doing these framesets so that the user can browse the site without the music player stop playing.

---

The result: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzx1x.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVl3S.png

Comment: HTML5 doesn't support framesets

Comment: Why the need for frames anyway? You can easily have the object in a div at the bottom of index

Answer (score 11):

You need to divide the frames within `<frameset>` tag, and need to avoid the `<body>` tag.
Only use `<frameset>` along with `<frame>`

You can refer to the [link](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/livedemo.php?p=examples/frames.html) for frame demo.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<frameset>` instead of `<body>`, not inside of `<body>`

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced a similar problem. You have to get rid of the `<body>` tag and put your `<frameset>` tag where the `<body>` tag would go.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
  <frame src="file:///Z:/web/as6.html">
  <frameset cols="25%,75%">
    <frame src="file:///Z:/web/asx.html">
    <frame src="file:///Z:/web/asz.html">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer to make it clear